# How do you change AWS.config in Clojure using Amazonica library?

Tags: amazon-web-services, clojure

In Ruby (using the Ruby AWS SDK) you can execute the following code to modify specific AWS configurations:

```
AWS.config(
  :use_ssl => false, 
  :s3_port => 49154,
  :s3_endpoint => "s3.spurious.localhost",
  :s3_force_path_style => true
)
```

The above snippet of code allows us to use a locally running service that fakes S3 (we've got other faked endpoints as well, such as SQS and DynamoDB but I've omitted them in the hope of providing a simple reduced example).

But how can this be achieved in Clojure using [Amazonica](https://github.com/mcohen01/amazonica)? There doesn't appear to be a straight forward `config` function.

The README suggests you either use: environment variables, Java System Properties, `~/.aws/credentials` or credentials provided by the EC2 metadata service.

None of which really fit our requirements.

BUT, the README also suggests that you can call `(defcredential)` up front and pass it a map of settings (see below example - which doesn't work because of an error `Unable to resolve symbol: defcredential`).

Also in the following example script I've tried using a specific S3 function and passing my configuration details as the first argument (as the README for Amazonica suggests you can do that - but that fails because it tried to make an HTTP request whilst I wasn't connected to the internet and so I could tell it wasn't using the locally running fake S3 service we're trying to direct to).

```
(ns foo-bar.core
  (:use [amazonica.aws.s3]))

(def cred {:access-key "development_access"
           :secret-key "development_secret"
           :endpoint   "eu-west-1"
           :s3-endpoint "s3.spurious.localhost"
           :s3-port 49154
           :client-config {:s3-endpoint  "s3.spurious.localhost" :s3-port 49154}})

(defcredential cred) ; ERROR: 
                     ; Unable to resolve symbol: defcredential

; Amazonica suggests all functions can except first arg
; which can be used as the credentials for the function
; I don't like it, but failing the use of defcredential I needed to try something
(create-bucket cred "testing") ; ERROR: 
                               ; Unable to execute HTTP request: testing.s3-eu-west-1.amazonaws.com
```

Comment: Not going to remove the Ruby tag but I think most people looking at Ruby questions will not be able to help you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`defcredential` comes from the `amazonica.core` namespace. See [here](https://github.com/mcohen01/amazonica/blob/a7f05fb0312df08c0727afa2741fe4591a788018/src/amazonica/core.clj#L116)

You need to `require` it in your `ns` declaration

```
(ns foo-bar.core
  (:use [amazonica.aws.s3])
  (:require [amazonica.core :refer [defcredential]))
```

As for specifying credentials in the client function (`create-bucket`), you want to set `:endpoint` instead of `:s3_endpoint` when specifying credentials inline in the function call. See the first example [here](https://github.com/mcohen01/amazonica#authentication) and [amazonica.core/keys->cred](https://github.com/mcohen01/amazonica/blob/a7f05fb0312df08c0727afa2741fe4591a788018/src/amazonica/core.clj#L108-L114)

Comment: Although this hasn't completely answered all my questions, it helped enough to justify setting this as the accepted answer. So thank you for that :-) I'm going to open a separate Clojure question that continues on from this one.